# How can I create different cell formats in Winform DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I'm binding to a DataTable.
The DataTable is a all numeric values.
There is a requirement that every n rows in the DataGridView has text in it, rather than the numeric values (to visually separate sections for the user).

I am happy to put this text data in the DataTable or in the DataGridView after binding, but I can't see a way to put this text data in either as the column formats for both require numeric data - I get a "can't put a string in a decimal" error for both.

Any ideas how I change the format of a particular row or cell in either the DataTable or DataGridView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide a handler for the DataGridView's `CellFormatting` event, such as:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle _myStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _myStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        // We could also provide a custom format string here 
        // with the _myStyle.Format property
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
        DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Every five rows I want my custom format instead of the default
        if (e.RowIndex % 5 == 0)
        {
            e.CellStyle = _myStyle;
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

For assistance on creating your own styles, refer to the `DataGridView.CellFormatting Event` topic in the online help.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Janus GridEx](http://www.janusys.com/janus/library/CustomPages/gridexnet.htm) for this type of non-standard behaviour.  (In part because it does much more than just this, like grouping and summing, cardview, etc.)  There are some good demos on the web site.

(Not a sales pitch; I just had a good experience using their component.)

[image: Screenshot of grouped and summed grid data]
<sub>(source: [janusys.com](http://www.janusys.com/janus/library/CustomPages/images/Hierarchical1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: So you don't think my requirement can be met with the standard DataGridView?

Comment: Well, I hesitate to say that because there are people here with more experience modifying WinForms control behaviour than me.  I'm frankly surprised no one else has piped up.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
// Set the data source.
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;

// Create a new text box column.
DataGridViewColumn c1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
const string C1_COL_NAME = "Custom1";
c1.Name = C1_COL_NAME;

// Insert the new column where needed.
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, c1);

// Text can then be placed in the rows of the new column.
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[C1_COL_NAME].Value = "Some text...";
```

The original data table bindings should still exist.